# C# Text before specific character

Tags: c#, string

I have this text

`"\This is a report 12000.csv\"`

I want the text before the period, ie `12000` .

Is there a something similar to a SubString and CharIndex that's available in SQL Server? Or some other easy method?

Comment: Did you google "C# substring"?  Your title says "text before specific character", what character?

Comment: Are you wanting a solution in C# or SQL? You have tagged as C# but ask for something similiar to `Substring` in SQL Server?

Comment: First search result for C# substring: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Yes there is something similar to substring and charindex. they are Substring and indexof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task achieved by using regular expressions.
The code below will extract any number from provided string

```
var yourString = @"\This is a report 12000.csv\";
var foundNum = Regex.Match(yourString, @"\d+").Value;
Console.Write(foundNum);
//output 12000
var yourString1 = @"\This is a 8080 report .csv\";
var foundNum1 = Regex.Match(yourString1, @"\d+").Value;
Console.WriteLine(foundNum1);
//output 8080
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter - tested in Linqpad 5 and working as expected